# Using OpenGeo Suite SDK to add Pan button?

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk

I´m building an app using OpenGeo Suite SDK and I need to add a Pan tool.

By default the pan option is activated but, if I enable another tool like a ZoomBoxAction, then I need to have a button to be able to go back to the pan tool.

I can’t find the tool I have to put on the bar to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the gxp_navigation tool and put it in the same toggleGroup as your other tools, see an example here:

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/static/script/app/GeoExplorer/Composer.js#L101